# breeze.js metadata and firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, metadata, breeze

Working on new SPA with angular and breeze and found that Firefox throws errors when Chrome does not. The app is able to work offline so when I first load the app (and therefore fill the cache) it works just fine. If I close the browser and re-open it, the app appears to load correctly. As soon as I click on anything that triggers a query from breeze it throws a "JSON is null" error.

I then tried to load the metadata on the client (importMetadata) based on advice found here on SO. 
I created the dataService with hasServerMetadata as false but for some reason Firefox still triggers pulling metadata from the server. This does NOT happen with Chrome. I used Fiddler to watch the traffic in both cases.
Of course when Firefox makes the server call the metadata has already been populated and it throws an error that the entity type already exists in the metadata store.

Has anyone else had a similar issue? Any thoughts as to why this might be happening in Firefox but not in Chrome?

UPDATE:
In the factory I use to create the breeze entity manager I put in some logging to see if I can figure out what's going on. Here's the fn.

```
function createMetadataStore() {
        console.log('loading metadata from local js');
        var store = new breeze.MetadataStore();
        console.log(window.app.metadata);

        model.configureMetadataStore(store);

        store.importMetadata(window.app.metadata); //used for offline import of metadata

        console.log(store.hasMetadataFor(serviceName));
        console.log('should have the metadata now');

        return store;
    }
```

I see the metadata logged as expected, but immediately after the store.importMetadata(window.app.metadata) call the hasMetadataFor(serviceName) call returns false. 
I removed the model.configureMetadataStore call but that had no effect.
Any ideas as to WHY the hasMetadataFor call would be returning false immediately after importing metadata? Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE 2: Not sure why I had to do this, but explicitly adding the data service with store.addDataService(dataService); right after I create the store did the trick. Hopefully this will help someone else if they ever run into this situation.

UPDATE 3: Okay, the addDataService trick fixed one problem but the original 'JSON is null' error resurfaced. I have finally tracked it down and put this here in case anyone else runs into this. The issue was with the lz-string.js library I use to compress data for local storage. As it turns out you have to use compressToUTF16 and decompressFromUTF16 as the plain compress and decompress functions don't work on FireFox. (http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/guide.html)

So the chain of events was:
1. load data from the server, compress it and store it in local storage.
2. When loading the app offline, pull the compressed data from local storage, decompress it and pass it into breeze.importEntities - this is where it failed.

I tested for null when getting local storage, and that passed. Unfortunately, the call to import entities never received the JSON data. Switching to the UTF16 versions of the lz-string functions solved the problem. Finally works in Firefox and Chrome without any issues.

Comment: The requirement for store.addDataService(dataService) doesnt seem to be in breeze documentation. Thanks